# Windows Server 2012 Terminal Server Print job not removed after Printing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, printing, windows-terminal-services

we have Windows 2012 Terminal Server with latest Patches.
Installed is a Shar MX-M314n Network Printer with latest PCL6 drivers.
If I as "administrator" print a Test Page or a User (no administrator privileges) Prints via Notepad shared as Remote App the Print job is printed successfully but the job stays in the queue filling up and after about 150-180 Jobs stock in the queue the Printing Stops working.

The only way to clear out the printing queue is to delete the jobs manually and restart the print spooler via (net stop spooler && net start spooler). 
The Printer is also for testing installed on 2 local machines (windows 7 and windows xp) and the problem doesnt occure there!

I have Uploaded a screenshot here. http://postimg.org/image/z0a0fabkf/

Any ideas or Advise? Thx!

Comment: Have you made sure that the option `Keep printed documents` is NOT enabled?

Comment: yes I checked that its not selected that option!
http://postimg.org/image/3rbnpshhz/